# Issues when trying to upload multiple images from Multer using Jimp (Express) in NodeJS

Tags: arrays, node.js, image, upload, multer

I want to display multiple images on my website, using Multer (nodejs).

I have created the following function :

```
exports.upload = multer(options).array('photo',3);

exports.images = async (req, res, next) => {
    const imgArray = req.files;

    const imgFormat = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++ ) {
        imgFormat.push(imgArray[i].mimetype.split('/')[1] );
    }

    req.body.photo = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++ ) {
        req.body.photo.push(`${uuid.v4()}.${imgFormat[i]}`);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
        const imgDetails = imgArray[i];
        const photo = await jimp.read(imgDetails.buffer);
        await photo.resize(1200, jimp.AUTO);
        await photo.write(`./public/uploads/${(req.body.photo)}`)
    }
    next();
    console.log(req.body.photo);

};
```

I use mongoose to access my database. On MongoDB, I manage to retrieve the images without facing any issue :

[see what I get in MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTeuS.png)

 
But when I console.log req.body.photo, I get the following array :

```
 [ 'cdb88df7-149d-4506-9ec2-7550c32ace66.jpeg',
   'efd9113b-9bd1-410e-a402-e969bf7aa8e3.png',
   '6408dbdc-4093-44a9-91f1-e34e7c5918e1.jpeg' ]
```

In my memoryStorage, I save a string made of three images when I need them to be separated :

What i get : `cdb88df7-149d-4506-9ec2-7550c32ace66.jpeg,efd9113b-9bd1-410e-a402-e969bf7aa8e3.png,6408dbdc-4093-44a9-91f1-e34e7c5918e1.jpeg`

What I want : 
cdb88df7-149d-4506-9ec2-7550c32ace66.jpeg 
efd9113b-9bd1-410e-a402-e969bf7aa8e3.png 
6408dbdc-4093-44a9-91f1-e34e7c5918e1.jpeg

Getting the images separated from each other and not in an array make my code work, I have tested it.

Would you please tell me how to do so ? I ran out of ideas. Many thanks

Comment: I use PUG to display the html. When I make an "each" iteration on the array that I generate ([ '32af76f2-f0ae-4b5d-a956-853b8ea5583a.jpeg','ef837c56-5c07-4f91-bf8b-fdc097e64ed5.png','4d4ecba4-9df4-4a8d-9556-002405521b41.jpeg' ]) only the first image appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested, here is my final code that resolved all issues mentionned above :

```
exports.images = async (req, res, next) => {
    const imgArray = req.files;

    const imgFormat = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++ ) {
        imgFormat.push(imgArray[i].mimetype.split('/')[1] );
    }

    req.body.photo = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++ ) {
        req.body.photo.push(`${uuid.v4()}.${imgFormat[i]}`);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
        const imgDetails = imgArray[i];
        const photo = await jimp.read(imgDetails.buffer);
        await photo.resize(1200, jimp.AUTO);
        await photo.write(`./public/uploads/${(req.body.photo[i])}`)

    }
    next();

};
```

With this code, i am able to upload multiple images via multer and jimp.
Many thanks to @ for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could try and assign variables to your images using the new ES6's Array Destructuring

As from Docs:

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

hence like so

```
let [imageOne, imageTwo, imageThree] = req.body.photo;
```

Then you can use the images separately the way you want 
if you console.log() imageOne you will get

```
console.log(imageOne) //output cdb88df7-149d-4506-9ec2-7550c32ace66.jpeg
```

In you code you could implement it like this

```
 exports.upload = multer(options).array('photo',3);

exports.images = async (req, res, next) => {
const imgArray = req.files;

const imgFormat = [];
for(let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++ ) {
    imgFormat.push(imgArray[i].mimetype.split('/')[1] );
}

req.body.photo = [];
for(let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++ ) {
    req.body.photo.push(`${uuid.v4()}.${imgFormat[i]}`);
}

for (let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
    const imgDetails = imgArray[i];
    const photo = await jimp.read(imgDetails.buffer);
    await photo.resize(1200, jimp.AUTO);
    await photo.write(`./public/uploads/${(req.body.photo)}`)
}  

  setTimeout(() => {
   let [imageOne, imageTwo, imageThree] = req.body.photo;
 }, 450);


 setTimeout(() => {
    next();
  }, 600);
```

};

What if you tried and do this instead of the forloop to later identify what the actual problem is cause I think it might be  the loop

```
let [firstFile,secondFile,thirdFile] = req.files
 const photo1 = await jimp.read(firstFile.buffer);
 const photo2 = await jimp.read(secondFile.buffer);
 const photo3 = await jimp.read(thirdFile.buffer);

 await photo1.resize(600, jimp.AUTO);
 await photo2.resize(600, jimp.AUTO);
 await photo3.resize(600, jimp.AUTO);

await photo1.write(`./public/uploads/${(firstFile)}`);
await photo2.write(`./public/uploads/${(secondFile)}`);
await photo3.write(`./public/uploads/${(thirdFile)}`);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it out but it doesn't really work for my need.
Here what I get once images have been uploaded : https://i.ibb.co/k42n1qt/image.png

As you can seen I get the three images in the same string that displays only the first image.

Thanks

Comment: when you console.log the imageOne ,imageTwo and imageThree separately  what do you get

Comment: I do get them separated as you can see : https://i.ibb.co/0FNXjPn/image.png

It's when I write them in my memory storage using Jimp that they get merged : await photo.write(`./public/uploads/${(req.body.photo)}`) ?

Comment: could you try the new code at the bottom replace your for loop with something similar to that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @chuklore for your answer, Besides allowing me to learn a new ES6's practice, you helped me move forward with my problem. But I am still facing an issue after I have implemented your recommandation.

Now, I am able to get images separated from each other : i.ibb.co/n8TbdhM/image.png

So when I loop with PUG, I get three images as wanted BUT it always the same image : i.ibb.co/BTDPWN5/image.png

As you can see in the above screenshot, I am looping via PUG through what should have been three different images.

When I check those images in my memory storage, it's indeed the same image with different UUID.

So something must have gone wrong in my code but I cannot figure it out. When in console.log(imgDetails.buffer), I get three different buffer, not always the same. So I don't know where the issue is coming from :

console.log(imgDetails.buffer) : https://i.ibb.co/XVFzz4x/image.png

Here is my code again :

```
exports.images = async (req, res, next) => {
    // get all images details
    const imgArray = req.files;
    // get extension (pgn, jpeg...)
    const imgFormat = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++ ) {
        imgFormat.push(imgArray[i].mimetype.split('/')[1] );
    }
    // get unique ID by image
    req.body.photo = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++ ) {
        req.body.photo.push(`${uuid.v4()}.${imgFormat[i]}`);
    }
    // unpack images from the array
    let [imageOne, imageTwo, imageThree] = req.body.photo;

    for (let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
        const imgDetails = imgArray[i];
        // get buffer for each image
        const photo = await jimp.read(imgDetails.buffer);
        await photo.resize(600, jimp.AUTO);
        await photo.write(`./public/uploads/${(imageOne)}`);
        await photo.write(`./public/uploads/${(imageTwo)}`);
        await photo.write(`./public/uploads/${(imageThree)}`)
    }
    next();

};
```

I can provide details about the rest of my code if needed. Thanks